# How can I link Photo Posts to the permalink page of a Tumblr blog?

Tags: tumblr

I have a Tumblr photoblog and what's annoying is that if you click on the image of a photopost you're linked to the permalink of that image alone.

Is there a way to link to the permalink page of the whole post instead?

Disqus comments don't make sense if nobody ever reaches the permalink page of our posts.

There's the same problem with post formats like Videos or Music too. No post title to click on means no easily accessible link to the permalink page which results in no Disqus comments.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `{Permalink}` option using the anchor tag and the div tag applied to your Photo block

```
{block:Photo}
   <div class="photo post">
      <a href="{Permalink}">
         <div>
            <img src="{PhotoUrl-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">
         </div>
       </a>
      {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
   </div>
{/block:Photo}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a date/time link at the bottom of the post that links to the permalink for that post.

[image: Tumblr screen shot]

That link, for instance, leads to http://rummelplatz.tumblr.com/post/13243111016/bokeh

Answer (score 0):

On the main page, if you hover over the respective post, the black overlay with the post's details appears; the hour (e.g. **7:06am** for the screenshot below) links to the permalink for the respective post.

[image]

Comment: That's not the theme that was being used when I left my answer.